# Selecting MappedSuperclass from the database (Hibernate)

Tags: java, hibernate

## Problem

I have a `@MappedSuperclass` called Data as the parent of every Entity in my database. It contains common attributes like Id etc. I then have an entity that extends Data which is also a `@MappedSuperclass` due to common functionality of its subclasses. The mapping in my database is correct.

Here is an example of my hierarchy

```
@MappedSuperclass
Data  
 |  @MappedSuperclass
 +- Employee  
 |      |  @Entity
 |      +- FullTimeEmployee
 |      |  @Entity
 |      +- PartTimeEmployee
 |  @Entity
 +- Store
```

And the tables are correctly mapped:

```
FullTimeEmployee  
PartTimeEmployee  
Store
```

Is there anyway to query the database for all Employee subclasses (FullTimeEmployee, PartTimeEmployee) as instances of Employee without referring the name of the subclasses in the query?

Something like

```
List<Employee> allEmployees = getAllEmployees();
```

The idea is that whenever I decide to create another subclass of Employee (i.e. AllDayEmployee) I will not have to change the query to include the name.

---

## Solution

So, as [Gregory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427439/selecting-mappedsuperclass-from-the-database-hibernate/1427490#1427490) correctly pointed out, this is not possible with `@MappedSuperclass`. So I changed it into @Entity and, since I wanted to preserve a table for each subclass I used `InheritanceType.JOINED`.

So the above hierarchy is now

```
@MappedSuperclass
Data  
 |  @Entity
 |  @Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
 +- Employee  
 |      |  @Entity
 |      +- FullTimeEmployee
 |      |  @Entity
 |      +- PartTimeEmployee
 |  @Entity
 +- Store
```

And the tables are still:

```
FullTimeEmployee  
PartTimeEmployee  
Store
```

So now, to get all Employees I simply call:

```
entityManager.createQuery("from Employee").getResultList();
```

Comment: What if I need two different `@SequenceGenerator` for FullTimeEmployee and PartTimeEmployee (I'm using Oracle sequences)? Being an Entity I have to specify the `@Id` on the Employee class.

Comment: If you are doing this in the context of spring-data-repositories (`@Repository`/`@NoRepositoryBean`), check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70260215/using-mappedsuperclass-in-spring-repository-query/78232979#78232979

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No if you are using @MappedSuperclass

The reason for this is that when you define base class as @MappedSuperclass, there is no table generated for the base class, instead all of the properties are replicated in the concrete tables. In your example only FullTimeEmployee, PartTimeEmployee and Store tables would exist.

If you want to be able to query for base class entities you need to select different mapping for base classes. Use @Inheritance annotation on the base class and select one of the 3 possible mapping strategies - SINGLE TABLE, TABLE PER CLASS or JOINED

Answer (score 1):

I seem to be able to do this (although using InheritanceType.JOINED) with hibernate 5.0.8, java 1.8.0_73 and Oracle 12c - either I am misunderstanding or maybe hibernate has changed..

I have the following hierarhcy:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
CommonRoot
 |
 |  @MappedSuperclass
 +- Mapped
        |  @Entity(name="Concrete1")
        |  @Table(name="CON1")
        +- Concrete1
        |
        |  @Entity(name="Concrete2")
        |  @Table(name="CON2")
        +- Concrete2
```

And I can do the following HQL:

```
SELECT entityId FROM com.hibernatetest.Mapped ORDER BY entityId ASC
```

which gives these 2 SQL statements:

```
select concrete2x0_.entityId as col_0_0_ from CON2 concrete2x0_ order by concrete2x0_.entityId ASC
select concrete1x0_.entityId as col_0_0_ from CON1 concrete1x0_ order by concrete1x0_.entityId ASC
```

and the warning

```
WARN: HHH000180: FirstResult/maxResults specified on polymorphic query; applying in memory!
```

Not sure what they mean though, as this can be done with SQL as:

```
(select entityId from CON2
union all
select entityId from CON1)
order by entityId ASC
```

(And you can also add limit/rownum clauses to that if you desire, although that gets a bit clunky:

```
select * from (
(select * from (select entityId from CON2 order by entityId ASC) where rownum <= 10)
UNION ALL
(select * from (select entityId from CON1 order by entityId ASC) where rownum <= 10)
) where rownum <= 10 order by entityId ASC
```

Not sure why hibernate shouldn't be able to do this - might suggest it to them.)

Comment: I don't understand how `@MappedSuperclass` and `@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)` can be on the same class - they seem to be contradictory.

Answer (score 0):

Yes

```
FROM Employee WHERE Employee.<employee only properties> = someValue
```

But only, as the others have said here, if the Employee entity is mapped.  You don't need to even map it to its' own table. See the mapping strategies in Hibernate.

Comment: +1 Yes. In Hibernate, you can select for an abstract class, you will get all subclasses as well. The example given is to query for Object, that will return the whole database! :-)

Comment: Given that Employee is an abstract class that has a @MappedSuperclass annotation, I want to get all subclass instances of Employee. "from Employee" query throws a QuerySyntaxException: Employee is not mapped"

Comment: Please see my answer for why it won't work with @MappedSuperclass

Comment: @Gregory: I went on the assumption that Employee was mapped as an entity.  I will update my response to reflect this.

Comment: I also updated my question to make it more clear which is which