# EclipseLink: Query to MappedSuperclass fails

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

My application is a store selling fishes, aquariums etc. I want to get a list of top 10 items among all the items based on sales count. I use the following class:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name="getTopItems",query="SELECT x FROM FishStoreItem x ORDER BY x.salescnt DESC, x.title DESC")
})
public abstract class FishStoreItem 
       extends DomainSuperClass implements Serializable {
......
}
```

Problem is in the following exception:

> Exception [EclipseLink-8034] (Eclipse
>   Persistence Services -
>   2.0.0.v20091127-r5931): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
>   Exception Description: Error compiling
>   the query [getTopItems: SELECT x FROM
>   FishStoreItem x ORDER BY x.salescnt
>   DESC, x.title DESC]. Unknown entity
>   type [FishStoreItem].

Same code works fine with Apache OpenJpa 2.0.0, but fails with EclipseLink ver 2.1.0, 2.0.1, 1.0.

P.S. I've already found [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427439/selecting-mappedsuperclass-from-the-database-hibernate) solution for Hibernate, but I want to be sure that it is impossible for EclipseLink too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A mapped superclass is not an entity and does not allow querying, persisting, or relationships to the superclass (see [Mapped Superclasses](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance#Mapped_Superclasses)).

This is confirmed in Apache OpenJPA 2.0 User's Guide:

> #### [1.3. Mapped Superclass](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.0.0/apache-openjpa-2.0.0/docs/manual/jpa_overview_meta.html#jpa_overview_meta_embeddablesuper)
>
> A *mapped superclass* is a non-entity
>   class that can define persistent state
>   and mapping information for entity
>   subclasses. Mapped superclasses are
>   usually abstract. Unlike true
>   entities, you cannot query a mapped
>   superclass, pass a mapped superclass
>   instance to any `EntityManager` or
>   Query methods, or declare a persistent
>   relation with a mapped superclass
>   target. You denote a mapped superclass
>   with the `MappedSuperclass` marker
>   annotation.
>
> ...
>
> **Note**
>
> OpenJPA allows you to query on mapped
>   superclasses. A query on a mapped
>   superclass will return all matching
>   subclass instances. OpenJPA also
>   allows you to declare relations to
>   mapped superclass types; however, you
>   cannot query across these relations.

So, while OpenJPA allows your query, this is beyond JPA. Don't expect it to work with any JPA provider.

Answer (score 2):

Can you confirm that you simply want a separate query run for every entity subclass and the results aggregated together?

This is similar to TABLE_PER_CLASS querying.

I have built an extension for EclipseLink in the past that can handle such querying and we can investigate adding it to the project if there is community interest and we can nail down the requirements.

Doug

Answer (score -1):

That code also works fine with [DataNucleus](http://www.datanucleus.org) as a JPA implementation. Being able to query for instances of a mapped superclass, whilst being beyond the JPA spec, is a very reasonable thing to require, and we believe in providing such things. After all the persistence provider knows which subclasses there are of that mapped superclass so makes little sense to not allow the user such a facility.

Comment: Is this stil the case? I ran across this today and am using version datanucleus-accessplatform-full-deps-3.1.4 . I am getting "Type <myType> is not a known entity type" when trying to do a criteriaquery using the  @MappedSuperclass class. It is definitely being enhanced but I am unable to query on the base mapped super class type. I am switching from openjpa and running into this problem. Is there a unit test for this in the code datanucleus code base I can use as a reference.

Comment: We have unit tests for such functionality. Worked then. Worked now. Works in the future