# Hibernate Mapped Superclass relationships and overriding

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I have an abstract MappedSuperClass, Participant, which is extended by three kinds of 'Participant'. Each one then uses its own kind of 'Project', also an abstract MappedSuperClass. However, I want the base class to know about Projects so I can write generic code to interact with Participants. How do I specify this using Hibernate annotations? and how will I override it in the ExtendedParticipant and ExtendedProject classes?

Each Participant type, and each Project type, have their own database tables with existing data and ids (not unique across tables) that I cannot change.

The following code gives me the IDE error "Many to one attribute should not be 'Mapped Superclass'".

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Participant implements Persistable {

    ...

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "project_id")
    public Project getProject() {
        return project;
    }

    public void setProject(Project project) {
        this.project = project;
    }

    ...
}
```

and the Project class is much the same with the same problem:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Project implements Persistable {

    ...

    @OneToMany
    public List<Participant> getParticipants() {
        return participants;
    }

    public void setProject(List<Participant> participants) {
        this.participants = participants;
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A mapped superclass is not an Entity, it can't be part of an association. So map your classes as entities and either introduce a mapped superclass "above" them or use a `TABLE_PER_CLASS` strategy.

#### See also

- [EclipseLink: Query to MappedSuperclass fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178187/eclipselink-query-to-mappedsuperclass-fails/3178330#3178330)
- [Hibernate - Persisting polymorphic joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928916/hibernate-persisting-polymorphic-joins/2929796#2929796)

Comment: Thanks Pascal, that make sense. I saw another post you had commented on about this but I'm still unsure what to do about it. There must be a way to set up all the relationships using base classes?

Comment: @Andrew: Well, why are they mapped superclass? Can't you put the common properties in a class above them? Another "option" would be to map them as entities and use a TABLE_PER_CLASS strategy.

Comment: The 3 ExtendedParticipant classes share many field names, so I had hoped to put all that into the base class, which is why I chose a Mapped SuperClass. I guess I could have a base class with no mappings, but then I would have to include every field in every ExtendedParticipant...

Answer (score 0):

Seems possible to have relations defined through the mappedsuperclass
according to the following

- [jboss_docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#d0e1168)
- [another_stackoverflow_thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442845/best-practises-for-polymorphic-jpa-via-annotations)
- [object_db_doc](http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/MappedSuperclass)

Answer (score 0):

Docs said it's possible, but superclass isn't abstract in example
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/MappedSuperclass.html