# How to refer to a parent Object annotated with @MappedSuperclass from a child object?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

How can i refer my child object to it's parent which are annotated with @MappedSuperclass? These are my classes:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class Person extends BaseEntity {}

@Entity
@Table(name = "employee", catalog = "enrollment_system", uniqueConstraints =
@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"reference", "emp_number"}))
public class Employee extends Person implements Serializable{}

@MappedSuperclass
public class BackGroundHistory extends BaseEntity {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
    @ForeignKey(name = "fk_person_history")
    private Person person;

 }

@Entity
@Table(name = "educational_history", catalog = "enrollment_system")
public class EducationalHistory extends BackGroundHistory implements java.io.Serializable {}
```

and during run time, i am getting this error:

`Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on entities.EducationalHistory.person references an unknown entity: entities.Person`

I am doing this, to avoid multiple declaration on `BackGroundHistory` class since aside from, class `Employee` I also have class `Applicant` and class `Student`.

Comment: from that what i remember using jpa ages ago, class with annotation @mappedsuperclass is not entity, and it doesn't have a table, hence cant be used for mapping relations

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate Mapped Superclass relationships and overriding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227854/hibernate-mapped-superclass-relationships-and-overriding)

Answer (score 0):

A mapped super-class is not an Entity, it's just used to extends or for inherit property like a `ID , CREATE_TIME , UPDATE_TIME ..etc`