# Query on attribute from @MappedSuperclass

Tags: hibernate

I have something like the following

```
@MappedSuperclass public abstract class Foo {
    @Column private String myId;
 }

@Entity public class Bar extends Foo {
}

@Entity public class Baz extends Foo {
}
```

But I now want to query for all instances of `Bar` and `Baz` using `myId` but my query gets rejected:

> org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Foo is not mapped [from
>   Foo foo where foo.myId = :myId]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you query sucessfully on the 2 entitys if you query each one seperately ?

Something like:

```
Collection<Bar> bars = (Bar) entityManager.createQuery("From Bar bar
    where bar.myId=:myId").setParameter("myId", myId).getResultList();
```

?

The answer is due to only having tables for concrete classes, if you look here
[clearer answer to identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427439/selecting-mappedsuperclass-from-the-database-hibernate)